# Pass options to QuillJS's module extensions through Quill.register

Tags: javascript, quill

I would like to upload an image to AWS s3 before I add it to the editor. I would like to do it inside ImageBlot because I am using `insertEmbed` in several places. This is the example code by the QillJS team.

```
Quill.register(ImageBlot);

export class ImageBlot extends BlockEmbed {

  static create(value) {
    const node = super.create();
    node.setAttribute('alt', value.alt);
    node.setAttribute('src', value.url);
    return node;
  }

  static value(node) {
    return {
      alt: node.getAttribute('alt'),
      url: node.getAttribute('src')
    };
  }
}

ImageBlot.blotName = 'image';
ImageBlot.tagName = 'img';
```

Is it possible to add custom functions to `ImageBlot` through `Quill.register` or any other way? I am using React and Redux, hence my actions have to be connected and can't just be imported.

Comment: ImageBlot is just a class so you can just add methods on it as you would any class? You then need to register your custom ImageBlot so it is used.

Comment: @jhchen yeah, I added functions to the prototype and it works. Thanks.